# the fetch response respond with empty object Promise

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm using API from GitHub to get the repositories of organization, but when i using fetch the response.json() responds with empty object , here's my code:

```
url = "https://api.github.com/orgs/octokit/repos";
fetch(url,{method: 'GET'})
.then((response)=>{console.log(response.json());})
.catch(()=>{console.log('err');});
```

the response is `Promise { <state>: "pending" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two `.then()`, the first one for the returned `Promise` and the second one for the response from said `Promise` :

```
url = "https://api.github.com/orgs/octokit/repos";
fetch(url,{method: 'GET'})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```